# Кликер в фоновом режиме

Tags: python

Как на python написать кликер чтобы он по заголовку окна находил нужное приложение и относительно его внутренних координат кликал по нужным в фоне (чтобы моя мышка не задействовалась и он работал как бы в фоне) ?

Comment: как вы представляет клик (активное действие!) в фоне?

Comment: Запусти в контейнере

Answer (score 0):

```
def control_click(x, y, handle, button='left'):

    l_param = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)

    if button == 'left':
        win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN,
                             win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)
        win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP,
                             win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)

    elif button == 'right':
        win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, 0, l_param)
        win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP, 0, l_param)
```

Winapi